# Mac Pro 5,1 firmware update for booting APFS

Tags: macos, firmware, mac-pro, apfs

When High Sierra came out, I opted to not update my filesystem version, out of caution. Now that it’s been out for a while, and my MacBook Pro has had no issues, I’d like to upgrade my MacBook Pro 5,1 to APFS.

I naively tried by booting into recovery mode, launching Disk Utility, and selecting “Update to APFS.” Good thing I just backed up, because this made my machine no longer boot.

Searching around, it appears that High Sierra included a firmware update that let machines boot from APFS volumes, which would explain why my machine would no longer boot after updating the boot volume.

I can’t find a way to retroactively apply that firmware patch, and Google is failing me. My backup plan is to download a High Sierra installer and try installing it from scratch, and hope I get a chance to select APFS and the firmware update. But I’d like a smoother path, if anyone has one.

Comment: This outdated, no longer updated page from Apple comes close: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518 but the .pkg firmware installer won't run on my Mojave installation. The "downgrade to High Sierra" option is looking like what I need to do.

Comment: It turned out my machine was booting fine, but the updated video card wasn't showing the "boot options" screen. So I reinstalled the original graphics card, and was able to use the GUI to install APFS and macOS Catalina.

Comment: The Mac Pro 5,1 is not Catalina-compatible, without using the DOSdude patch, even if you have a Metal-capable GPU. High Sierra shouldn't have let you install in the first place without the firmware update, nor would Mojave… so the entire question becomes unclear.

Comment: One of my attempts included DOSDude, but once I could boot with the Radeon RX580, I didn't think DOSDude was involved. I could have been wrong. In any case, my 5,1+RX580 is running Catalina just great now.

Comment: You must still have the hack in place, then, because the 5,1 is not Catalina-capable, even with a Metal GPU. 6,1 is the only Mac Pro that can run it, according to Apple. None of the 5,1s here have the option… not that I'd want it, tbh ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Years later (2022), thanks to [Open Core Legacy Patcher](https://github.com/dortania/Opencore-Legacy-Patcher), this 12-year-old system is running macOS Monterey just fine, even showing video during the boot process.

One thing I did have to do was follow [the instructions here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mp5-1-what-you-have-to-do-to-upgrade-to-mojave-bootrom-upgrade-instructions-thread.2142418/) about updating my system's firmware. That involved downloading macOS Mojave, but was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Excellent followup answer here! Great work.